# move text in center for all lines

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I render such an item in a FlatList. When the name is too long, it extends to the next line, which is okay but I want that it should still be in the center. The second line should also be positioned in the center. For example, **Ross** should also approximately come under **Vom**. Is that possible?

```
export const FriendEntry: React.FunctionComponent<FriendEntryProps> = ({
  friend,
  currentUserId,
}) => {

  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Thumbnail
          style={styles.thumbnail}
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatars-xmas-giveaway/128/afro_woman_female_person-512.png',
          }} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>{userName}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.deleteButtonContainer}>
        <Button
          rounded
          style={styles.deleteButton}
          <Icon name="trash-o" size={moderateScale(20)} color="black" />
        </Button>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: moderateScale(20),
    padding: moderateScale(20),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(8),
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    height: moderateScale(110),
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  userName: {
    paddingRight: 55,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31C283',
    width: moderateScale(45),
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  deleteButtonContainer: {
    paddingTop: 12,
    marginRight: 2,
  },
  thumbnail: {
    height: 85,
    width: 85,
    marginLeft: 2,
    paddingRight: 0,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  nameContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: Add `alignItems: 'center'` to styles.item.

Comment: try  justifyContent: "center" on name container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add textAlign: 'center' to your userName object.

```
userName: {
    paddingRight: 55,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align them vertically use `alignItems: 'center'` in

```
items: {
  alignItems: 'center'
}
```

That way `TouchableOpacity` and `View`s will be vertically aligned in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Use textAlign for your text's style

```
userName: {
    //other styles
    textAlign: 'center'
}
```